I am unable to properly remove items from an array
I have a nextjs and expressjs web application and I initially thought that what I wanted to do would be easier but I have not been able to achieve what I want to do. The task is for me to remove selected items from an array.
The client side has items that I selected and stored in an array, this array of selected strings would be sent to the backend. I would need to remove those items from the array storing the items in backend.
However, I find out that if I select just one item, it deletes properly but if I select more than 2, it would delete the first two items and will not delete the others.
Here is the code:
const participants = [
{
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecc'
},



const participants = [
{
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: 'd1430b68-ed73-41e7-b821-7042c7ca872e'
},


 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '26adb5de-7d36-48e4-b563-b0651953a11b'
},


 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
   participantId: '62f50356-fbbe-43f9-a26f-53ce004ba1eb'
  },



 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: 'ff1f42c9-ab33-4c60-a43f-888e138702a3'
},


{
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: 'ab32bed4-0e49-4950-b7b3-7149e0bc4c29'
},


{
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '8a0cd9f0-96f3-4ba9-8e0a-260204286c95'
 },

 
 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: 'ca977e1e-39b3-4fa1-9f9d-168fa5ff18b6'
  },
  
  {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '0414a3b1-6ad8-4d57-bf25-97f2d7878df5'
  },
  
  {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '27cbeb11-de62-41cc-8363-245501a7c0d8'
  },
  
   {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '42188c84-5e2e-465a-8398-c3b13b26b121'
  },
  
   {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: 'a26cac27-ae73-48e7-b3dc-4c68ce312406'
  },
  
   {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) -Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: 'a982ad28-f9f8-4e79-a054-892704cf4a27'
  },
  
];

let copiedArray = [...participants]

const selectedDemoIds = ['26adb5de-7d36-48e4-b563-b0651953a11b', 'd1430b68-ed73-41e7-b821-7042c7ca872e', 'a982ad28-f9f8-4e79-a054-892704cf4a27'];

const updatedCopiedArray = copiedArray?.filter((item, index)=>!selectedDemoIds?.includes(item?.participantId));

copiedArray = updatedCopiedArray;

console.log( participants?.length, copiedArray?.length); 



 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecd'
},


 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
   participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722eca'
  },



 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecgf'
},


{
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecz'
},


{
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecmh'
 },

 
 {
  packageName: 'The Egypt Experience - (06/28/2026 – 07/06/2026) - 
   Gold Level Double Occupancy (per person)',
   participantNameInfo: {
  participantFirstName: 'Monday',
  participantLastName: 'Everson',
  participantEmail: 'monday@gmail.com',
  participantPhoneNumber: '07876'
   },
  participantId: '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecka'
  },
]



const selectedDemoIds = ['6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecc', '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecd', '6fe28b2e-53bb-4de6-8d13-84af08722ecka']

let copiedArray = participants; this contains the items stored in the database that I would be deleting based on the selected id from the frontend.
 const selectedOrderedItemIds = req.body.selectedOrderedItemIds; This is an array of object that came from the frontend. Inside this array of objects, there are ids selected to be deleted from copiedArray
 const selectedPackageIndexes = findSelectedPackage?.map((item, index) => item?.selectedIndex); I had to create a new array that contains only the ids of selected item. This made it a simple string array.
const flatttedArray = selectedPackageIndexes?.flat(); some could be array inside array, I had to flat method to flatten the array into a single array of string ids.
Time to remove the items from copied array using the ids found inside flattedArray
const updatedCopiedArray = copiedArray?.filter((item, index) => !selectedDemoIds?.includes(item?.participantId)); 
copiedArray = updatedCopiedArray;
await OrderModel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: order?._id},
{    participantsData: copiedArray, }, {new: true});
Like I said earlier, the first 1 and 2 items get filtered out however, others won't. If I am selecting one item at a time, that means if I send just a single id to the backend to be filtered out, it filters that out. How do I write this to filter out all selected ids coming from the frontend no matter the number?

Do you specifically mean that your copiedArray?.filter(...) operation is returning an incorrect result?  If so, can you replicate this with a [mcve] using known hard-coded data?

Yes, the copiedArrat end up not filtering out all the selected ids in that flattedArray. It is just inconsistent. During my last test, I selected 7 items and there were 7 ids in the flattedArray and it ended filtering out the first 4 ids, leaving the last 2.  You may select 3 items and it will filter out first 2 and leave the last one. On my last test now, I selected 2 items, it filtered out the first item and left the last item. I don't know why it is acting this way.

Your code is disjointed and missing some variables we need to reproduce the problem.

@valve: A runnable [mcve] which demonstrates this would really go a long way to diagnosing it.  Most of the question above is just describing the behavior rather than demonstrating it.  A single call to .filter() on an array is something you can demonstrate in a runnable code snippet.

I have reproduced the code and it runs well. I cant figure out what could be causing the code in my local environment from running well. I have uncommented out the database update and simply console.log(coppiedArray) immediately after filter method was called on it locally, using similar data like the one I have here, I sent 3 ids to be filtered out, it filtered out the first 2 but properly filtered out the 3 when I reproduced here. I even hardcoded the ids directly and called the filter method and include method on the hardcoded copiedArray and hardcoded selectedIds, still the same issue.

I have seen the issue, a space was added in one of the methods that adds id to an array. Thanks because your suggestion that I should reproduce the code here made me to find out this mistake.
